# Flutter change password

Tags: flutter

I want to make a change password in my app using mysql but i dont know how to get the specific logged in id to change my password i have a dash board i am using cards on it so when i click the card with a name change password it will redirect
to this page i am using a mysql for my localdatabase.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Change Password'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff083663),
          ),
          body: Form(
            key: _key,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Change Password',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
```

//This is the field where you will enter the Current Password

```
  Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (e) {
                if (e.isEmpty) {
                  return "Please Enter Current Password";
                }
                return null;
              },
              obscureText: _secureText1,
              onSaved: (e) => c1 = e,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Current Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: showHide,
                    icon: Icon(_secureText1
                        ? Icons.visibility_off
                        : Icons.visibility),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Color(0xff083663),
                  )),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (e) {
                if (e.isEmpty) {
                  return "Please Enter New Password";
                }
                return null;
              },
              obscureText: _secureText2,
              onSaved: (e) => c2 = e,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'New Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    onPressed: showHide2,
                    icon: Icon(_secureText2
                        ? Icons.visibility_off
                        : Icons.visibility),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Color(0xff083663),
                  )),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()),
            ),
          ),
```

// this is the field for the verify password

```
  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      validator: (e) {
                        if (e.isEmpty) {
                          return "Verify Password";
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (e) => c3 = e,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Verify Password',
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            onPressed: showHide3,
                            icon: Icon(_secureText3
                                ? Icons.visibility_off
                                : Icons.visibility),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xff083663),
                          )),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 16.0),
                    child: Divider(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 250,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        check();
                      },
                      color: Color(0xffb5171d),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(
                            Icons.vpn_key,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Save Changes',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```